# Approach to cleaning Data in spark

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, nltk

I am a very new student of data engineering/machine learning and learning by myself. While working in a sample problem, I came across the following task of data cleaning

```
1. Remove extra whitespaces (keep one whitespace in between word but remove more 
than one whitespaces) and punctuations

2. Turn all the words to lower case and remove stop words (list from NLTK)

3. Remove duplicate words in ASSEMBLY_NAME column
```

Though I've worked on writing code to perform these task during assignments in college, I've never done it in a single piece of code (for any project) and I am looking out for guidance here from experts who can help me by pointing towards the best approach to get it done `(in python or scala)`

**Work done so far:**

**1. Read data from parquet file**

```
partFitmentDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("/mnt/blob/devdatasciencesto/pga-parts-forecast/raw/parts-fits/")

display(partFitmentDF)
```

[image]
 **2. Create table from DF**

```
partFitmentDF.createOrReplaceTempView("partsFits")
partFitmentDF.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").saveAsTable("partsFitsTable")
```

**3. Rearrange Data of fits_assembly_name in the table so that all the fits_assembly_name and fits_assembly_id roll over to single row for each distinct itemno**

```
%sql

select itemno, concat_ws(' | ' , collect_set(cast(fits_assembly_id as int))) as fits_assembly_id, concat_ws(' | ' ,collect_set(fits_assembly_name)) as fits_assembly_name 
from partsFitsTable 
WHERE itemno = 1014584
group by itemno
```

[image]

**P.S.**

**Sample Data from selected columns of partFitmentDF**

```
itemno  fits_assembly_id        fits_assembly_name
0450056 44011           OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A01EA09CA (4999202399920239A06)
0450056 135502          OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A02EA09CA/CB/CC (4999202399920239A06)
0450056 37884           OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A01EA05CA (4999202399920239A06)
0450056 19618           OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A06FA09CA/CB/CC (4999202399920239A06)
0450056 135021          OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A02EA05CA (4999202399920239A06)
0450056 4147            OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A04KA05CA (4999202359920235A06)
0450056 12003           OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A05FA09CA/CB/CC (4999202399920239A06)
```

**Now, I need to roll over these multiple rows into one row by item no *(all the assembly_name and id's belonging to one itemno should be in one row)* and then I need to perform task#1, 2 and 3 as listed at the very top to clean the fits_assembly_name column and save the processed data to final dataframe or table with itemno, fits_assembly_id and fits_assembly_name columns** but I am not sure how to get started in python to do it. Could you please help me by suggesting the approach *(and hint of code)* so that I can take this task further?

Comment: pyspark.ml.feature: RegexTokenizer, StopWordsRemover should be enough for your first two tasks, which returns an array of strings, use array_distinct(spark 2.4+ only) to remove dupes. concat_ws to convert the array into String if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Could you please share the skeleton of how to apply it? I am sorry if it's too much to ask. Since I am new to it, I am not sure how to apply it to ```fits_aeesbly_field``` of dataframe. For instance: I can write functions to remove punctuation or extra white spaces separately but I am confused about how to apply those functions to dataframe field i.e. fits_assembly_name. For example, ```code ' '.join(mystring.split())``` will remove two or more whitespaces and replace it with one but I am not sure how to apply this on fits_assembly_name field after sql processing.

Comment: what is your spark version? can you add some sample data and post the desired result?

Comment: @jxc: Spark version is 2.4.4 and I've posted few rows of sample data and updated query at the very bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the following works for you. I assumed that `df` is the dataframe after the groupby and collect_set you already ran:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover, RegexTokenizer
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
```

### Task-1: Use [RegexTokenizer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer)

use pattern `(?:\p{Punct}|\s)+` to split the string, save the result to `temp1` column. The resulting array of strings will have all items in lowercase, leading/trailing spaces are also removed.

```
tk = RegexTokenizer(pattern=r'(?:\p{Punct}|\s)+', inputCol='fits_assembly_name', outputCol='temp1')

df1 = tk.transform(df)
```

### Task-2: Use [StopWordsRemover](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover)

to remove stopwords and save result into `temp2` column:

```
sw = StopWordsRemover(inputCol='temp1', outputCol='temp2')

df2 = sw.transform(df1)
```

you can check all current stop words by typing `sw.getStopWords()`, check [loadDefaultStopWords(language)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover.loadDefaultStopWords) to switch to another language setting, or append your own Stopwords by:

```
mylist = sw.getStopWords() + ['my', 'black', 'list']
# then adjust the transformer to the following
sw = StopWordsRemover(inputCol='temp1', outputCol='temp2', stopWords=mylist)
```

At this point, you should have an array of strings column `temp2` with stop Words removed.

### Task-3:

use [array_distinct()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_distinct) to remove duplicates, concat_ws() to convert the array into a string, and then drop two temp columns:

```
df_new = df2.withColumn('fits_assembly_name', expr('concat_ws(" ", array_distinct(temp2))')) \
            .drop('temp1', 'temp2')
```

Let me know if you have any problems with the above code.

Comment: Thank a lot!!!!   It worked. It didn't do the roll-over of multiple rows into one row by item no (all the assembly_name and id's belonging to one itemno should be in one row). I'll try to find that at my end. Once again, thanks for the detailed instruction and kind help!!!

Comment: Quick note. It worked however, It didn't do the roll-over of multiple rows into one row by item no (all the assembly_name and id's belonging to one itemno should be in one row). Once the rollover is done then remove duplicates in each cell of column ```fits_assembly_name```.  For instance, remove duplicates from the data which is in the ```fits_assembly_name``` column in bottom screenshot. So, for instance, ```OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY``` should not be repeated more than once after the rollover is done.

Comment: I've posted a new question and marked it as solved. link ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58663008/fix-part-id-and-assembly-column-data-in-spark-2-4-4```

Comment: @SachinSharma, not sure what exactly you meant. But the code should be run after you have completed `groupby` and `collect_set`, so that all items for the same itemno should already be saved in the same row before this post-processing.

Comment: BTW. I submitted one solution for your new question, just let me know if you have any questions. have a good weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the either the SQL or pyspark functions.

- [The pyspark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)
- [The Spark SQL docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html)
- `trim(s)` -- returns string `s` with leading and trailing whitespace
- `regexp_replace(s, "\W")` -- returns string `s` with non alpha numeric characters ("punctuation") replaced by spaces
- `lower(s)` -- returns string `s` with all the characters in lower case
- `split(s)` -- returns an array of words in string `s` split where word boundaries are one or more spaces.
- `array_distinct(a)` -- returns the distinct elements of a

Put it all together like this in pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame( [Row(name="BODY, DECALS - Z19VF99LK/LE (702498)"), Row(name="     ABC  DEF ABC   ")] ) 
clean_df = df.withColumn("words", 
                         F.array_distinct(
                             F.split(
                               F.trim(
                                 F.regexp_replace(F.lower(df.name), "\W", " ")
                               )
                             , " +")
                         )
                        )
clean_df.show(truncate=False)
```

To produce a `words` column with the result:

```
+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|name                                |words                                |
+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|BODY, DECALS - Z19VF99LK/LE (702498)|[body, decals, z19vf99lk, le, 702498]|
|     ABC  DEF ABC                   |[abc, def]                           |
+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

I'm a bit unclear on the exact problem but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The task is to merge multiple rows into one as per itemno which is shown in the bottom screenshot then I want to write pipeline code to clean data for ```fits_assembly_name``` field. I can write functions to remove punctuation or extra white spaces separately but I am confused about how to apply those functions to dataframe field i.e. ```fits_assembly_name``` For example, code ```' '.join(mystring.split())``` will remove two or more whitespaces and replace it with one but I am not sure how to apply this on ```fits_assembly_name``` field.

Comment: If you have a dataframe `df` with column `fits_assembly_name` you can use `withColumn` and the same column name to replace the column with the result of a column expression. For example: `df.withColumn("fits_assembly_name", F.trim(df.fits_assembly_name))` will still have a `fits_assembly_name` column but it will have been trimmed of leading/trailing space.