# Approach to fix assembly_id and assembly_name column data in spark 2.4.4

Tags: python-3.x, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I've been working on data cleaning task in spark 2.4.4 but got stuck in following two tasks *(mentioned in question section)*. Following is the dataframe and questions details:

**1. Mount data and read parquet file in dataframe**

```
partFitmentRawDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("/mnt/blob/devdatasciencesto/pga-parts-forecast/raw/parts-fits/")
```

**2. Sample data**

```
display(partFitmentRawDF)
```

```
Itemno   Assembly_id    Assembly_name
0450056   44011         OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A01EA09CA (4999202399920239A06)
0450056   135502        OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A02EA09CA/CB/CC (4999202399920239A06)
0450056   37884         OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A01EA05CA (4999202399920239A06)
```

I've done other processing to make data look like above but I am stuck into following tasks

**3.Question**

**a.** If we look at row2 and column `Assembly_name` then there are three id's `A02EA09CA/CB/CC` but they've been merged in. Could you please suggest how to make it `A02EA09 A02EA09CB A02EA09CC`. Basically, all of the parts should have stand-alone id concatenated with one space in between. Another example of same problem is to change `DRIVE TRAIN, TRANSMISSION (6 SPEED) - V08AB26/GB26/LB26 ALL OPTIONS (49VICTRANS08)` to `DRIVE TRAIN, TRANSMISSION (6 SPEED) - V08AB26 V08GB26 V08LB26 ALL OPTIONS (49VICTRANS08)`or change `SUSPENSION (7043244) - S09PR6HSL/PS6HSL/HEL (49SNOWSHOCKFRONT7043244SB)` to `SUSPENSION (7043244) - S09PR6HSL S09PS6HSL S09PS6HEL (49SNOWSHOCKFRONT7043244SB)`.

**b.** Roll over multiple rows in `assemble_id and assembly_name column` belonging to same itemno to single row and remove duplicate words.

So following dataset

```
Itemno   Assembly_id    Assembly_name
0450056   44011         OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A01EA09CA (4999202399920239A06)
0450056   135502        OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A02EA09CA/CB/CC (4999202399920239A06)
0450056   37884         OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A01EA05CA (4999202399920239A06)
```

will result into below mentioned final dataset **(which doesn't have punctuations, more than one space between the words and duplicate words)**

```
Itemno   Assembly_id            Assembly_name
0450056  44011 135502 37884     OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY A01EA09CA 4999202399920239A06 A02EA09CA A02EA09CB A02EA09CC 4999202399920239A06
```

Could you please help me in this? Thanks in advance for kind help!

**Issues after testing JXC's solution**

**1. Concatenation issue**

If the initial dataset is as following

```
itemno  fits_assembly_id    fits_assembly_name
1322660 35459               DRIVE TRAIN, CLUTCH, PRIMARY - S09PR6HSL/PS6HSL/HEL (49SNOWDRIVECLUTCH09600TRG)
```

After **step-3**, it is doing the following

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|temp1                                                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[DRIVE, TRAIN, CLUTCH, PRIMARY, S09PR6HSL, S09PS6HSL, S09PS6HEL, 49SNOWDRIVECLUTCH09600TRG]|
```

Initially, it was `S09PR6HSL/PS6HSL/HEL` so it should change to `S09PR6HSL S09PS6HSL S09PR6HEL` but it is `S09PR6HSL S09PS6HSL S09PS6HEL`. 3rd item should be `S09PR6HEL` but it is `S09PS6HEL`. I believe it should take the part to be concatenated from the very first string and add it to all others after `/`.

**2. Underscore replacement:**
This is new because I just spotted a few rows with this. Sometimes string after `/` has underscores. In this case, letter *(of 1st string)* from the same position as of the underscore should replace `_` in second or later string from the very first string.  **For instance, if data is `DRIVE TRAIN, CLUTCH, PRIMARY - S09PR6HSL/PS_HSL/H_L (49SNOWDRIVECLUTCH09600TRG)` then it should change to `DRIVE TRAIN, CLUTCH, PRIMARY - S09PR6HSL S09PS6HSL S09PR6HSL (49SNOWDRIVECLUTCH09600TRG)`. Here, In `/PS_HSL/` `_` got replaced by value `6` because `PS_HSL` matches with `PR6HSL` so replace `_` with `6` and add `S09` to make it complete id which is  `S09PS6HSL`.** Basically, take data from the first string and append it to later strings *(after `/`)* if it's not the same length to make it complete id. If there's `_`, take data from the same position as of `_` from 1st string and replace it in later ID strings.

**3.** Separate substrings joined by `/` and store rest of the string in new column added to the same dataframe

*For example:*

[image]

**Issue after step0:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, ideally I would go with a **udf** to make things simple, but since this task is a good example of using Spark SQL higher-order functions... Might be a little verbose, so I split it into 4 steps. Let me know if it works and any questions are welcome:

### Step-1: convert string into array of strings

split the string by the pattern **`(?:(?!/)\p{Punct}|\s)+'))`** which is consecutive
punctuation(except `/`) or spaces, then filter out the items which are EMPTY (leading/trailing). A temporary column `temp1` is used to save the intermediate columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, expr

df1 = df.withColumn('temp1', split('Assembly_name', r'(?:(?!/)\p{Punct}|\s)+')) \
        .withColumn('temp1', expr("filter(temp1, x -> x <> '')"))

df1.select('temp1').show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|temp1                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[OIL, PUMP, ASSEMBLY, A01EA09CA, 4999202399920239A06]                                |
|[OIL, PUMP, ASSEMBLY, A02EA09CA/CB/CC, 4999202399920239A06]                          |
|[OIL, PUMP, ASSEMBLY, A01EA05CA, 4999202399920239A06]                                |
|[DRIVE, TRAIN, TRANSMISSION, 6, SPEED, V08AB26/GB26/LB26, ALL, OPTIONS, 49VICTRANS08]|
|[SUSPENSION, 7043244, S09PR6HSL/PS6HSL/HEL, 49SNOWSHOCKFRONT7043244SB]               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Step-2: convert temp1 to array of arrays

split the array items again using `/`, so that all part-id on their own array item

```
df2 = df1.withColumn('temp1', expr("transform(temp1, x -> split(x, '/'))"))
df2.select('temp1').show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|temp1                                                                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[OIL], [PUMP], [ASSEMBLY], [A01EA09CA], [4999202399920239A06]]                                           |
|[[OIL], [PUMP], [ASSEMBLY], [A02EA09CA, CB, CC], [4999202399920239A06]]                                   |
|[[OIL], [PUMP], [ASSEMBLY], [A01EA05CA], [4999202399920239A06]]                                           |
|[[DRIVE], [TRAIN], [TRANSMISSION], [6], [SPEED], [V08AB26, GB26, LB26], [ALL], [OPTIONS], [49VICTRANS08]] |
|[[SUSPENSION], [7043244], [S09PR6HSL, PS6HSL, HEL], [49SNOWSHOCKFRONT7043244SB]]                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Step-3: use aggregate to reset part-ids

The aggregate function will operate on the inner arrays:

```
df3 = df2.withColumn('temp1', expr("""

       flatten(
         transform(temp1, x ->
           transform(sequence(1, size(x)), i ->
             aggregate(
                 sequence(1, i)
               , x[0]
               , (acc,j) -> concat(substr(acc, 1, length(x[0])-length(x[j-1])), x[j-1])
             )
           )
         )
       )

    """))

df3.select('temp1').show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|temp1                                                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[OIL, PUMP, ASSEMBLY, A01EA09CA, 4999202399920239A06]                                         |
|[OIL, PUMP, ASSEMBLY, A02EA09CA, A02EA09CB, A02EA09CC, 4999202399920239A06]                   |
|[OIL, PUMP, ASSEMBLY, A01EA05CA, 4999202399920239A06]                                         |
|[DRIVE, TRAIN, TRANSMISSION, 6, SPEED, V08AB26, V08GB26, V08LB26, ALL, OPTIONS, 49VICTRANS08] |
|[SUSPENSION, 7043244, S09PR6HSL, S09PS6HSL, S09PS6HEL, 49SNOWSHOCKFRONT7043244SB]             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Where:**

- `transform(temp1, x -> func1(x))` : iterate through each item in the array *temp1* to run *func1(x)*, x is the inner array (array of strings)
- `func1(x)` mentioned above is another transform function which iterates through the *sequence(1, size(x))* and run *func2(i)* on each *i*:

  ```
  transform(sequence(1, size(x)), i -> func2(i))
  ```
- `func2(i)` mentioned above is an aggregate function, which iterates through the *sequence(1,i)*, with initial value of *x[0]* and accumulate/reduce using the function:

  ```
  (acc,j) -> concat(substr(acc, 1, length(acc)-length(x[j-1])), x[j-1])
  ```

  **Note:** `substr()` position is 1-based and `array-indexing` is 0-based, thus we need x[j-1] to refer to the current array item in the above reduce/aggregate function
- finally, run `flatten()` to merge the inner arrays

  This step is doing something like the following pysudo-loop:

  ```
  for x in temp1:
    for i in range(1, size(x)+1):
      acc = x[0]
      for j in range(1,i+1):
        acc = concat(substr(acc, 1, length(acc)-length(x[j-1])), x[j-1])
  ```

### Step-4: merge and drop duplicates

```
df4 = df3.groupby('Itemno').agg(
      expr("concat_ws(' ', array_distinct(flatten(collect_list(temp1)))) AS Assembly_names")
    , expr("concat_ws(' ', collect_set(Assembly_id)) as Assembly_ids")
  )
```

**Where:**

- use *collect_list()* to get an array of arrays(temp1 which is array of strings)
- use *flatten()* to convert the above into array of strings
- use *array_distinct()* to drop duplicates
- use *concat_ws()* to convert above array into a string

  ```
  df4.select('Assembly_names').show(truncate=False)
  +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |Assembly_names                                                                         |
  +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY A01EA09CA 4999202399920239A06 A02EA09CA A02EA09CB A02EA09CC A01EA05CA|
  |SUSPENSION 7043244 S09PR6HSL S09PS6HSL S09PS6HEL 49SNOWSHOCKFRONT7043244SB             |
  |DRIVE TRAIN TRANSMISSION 6 SPEED V08AB26 V08GB26 V08LB26 ALL OPTIONS 49VICTRANS08      |
  +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  ```

### UPDATE:

The first one is simple to fix, it's much easier than the existing one (no need aggregate). For the 2nd one, the following solution requires to iterate through the string char by char which could be slow. If so, we might have to check using udf.

Below are the changes:

- **Step-1:** Just add underscore to be excluded from the punctuation: (notice if any underscore shows in other places of the text, might have to run regexp_replace first to clean them up)

  ```
  df1 = df.withColumn('temp1', split('Assembly_name', r'(?:(?![/_])\p{Punct}|\s)+')) \ 
          .withColumn('temp1', expr("filter(temp1, x -> x <> '')"))
  ```
- **Step-2:** split the array of array further into array of arrays of arrays, the inner-most array has split string into chars. reverse the innermost array so it's easy for comparison.

  ```
  df2 = df1.withColumn('temp1', expr("transform(temp1, x -> split(x, '/'))")) \
           .withColumn('temp1', expr("transform(temp1, x -> transform(x, y -> reverse(split(y, ''))) )"))
  ```
- **Step-3:** Use transform() instead of aggregate() to reset part-ids. we check *y[i]* (the item of the innermost array) if it's NULL or is an underscore, then replace it with the corresponding item from *x[0][i]*. then we reverse the array and using concat_ws(''..) to convert it back into string.

  ```
  df3 = df2.withColumn('temp1', expr("""

     flatten(
       transform(temp1, x ->
         transform(x, y ->
           concat_ws('', 
             reverse(
               transform(sequence(0, size(x[0])-1), i -> IF(y[i] is NULL or y[i] == '_', x[0][i], y[i]))
             )
           )
         )
       ) 
     ) 

  """))
  ```

Below is the result from the above

```
df3.select('temp1').show(truncate=False)                                                                           
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|temp1                                                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[OIL, PUMP, ASSEMBLY, A01EA09CA, 4999202399920239A06]                                        |
|[OIL, PUMP, ASSEMBLY, A02EA09CA, A02EA09CB, A02EA09CC, 4999202399920239A06]                  |
|[OIL, PUMP, ASSEMBLY, A01EA05CA, 4999202399920239A06]                                        |
|[DRIVE, TRAIN, TRANSMISSION, 6, SPEED, V08AB26, V08GB26, V08LB26, ALL, OPTIONS, 49VICTRANS08]|
|[SUSPENSION, 7043244, S09PR6HSL, S09PS6HSL, S09PR6HEL, 49SNOWSHOCKFRONT7043244SB]            |
|[DRIVE, TRAIN, CLUTCH, PRIMARY, S09PR6HSL, S09PS6HSL, S09PR6HSL, 49SNOWDRIVECLUTCH09600TRG]  |
|[DRIVE, TRAIN, CLUTCH, PRIMARY, S09PR6HSL, S09PS6HSL, S09PR6HSL, 49SNOWDRIVECLUTCH09600TRG]  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The field before processing:

```
df.select('Assembly_name').show(truncate=False)                                                                    
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Assembly_name                                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A01EA09CA (4999202399920239A06)                               |
|OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A02EA09CA/CB/CC (4999202399920239A06)                         |
|OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY - A01EA05CA (4999202399920239A06)                               |
|DRIVE TRAIN, TRANSMISSION (6 SPEED) - V08AB26/GB26/LB26 ALL OPTIONS (49VICTRANS08)|
|SUSPENSION (7043244) - S09PR6HSL/PS6HSL/HEL (49SNOWSHOCKFRONT7043244SB)           |
|DRIVE TRAIN, CLUTCH, PRIMARY - S09PR6HSL/PS_HSL/H_L (49SNOWDRIVECLUTCH09600TRG)   |
|DRIVE TRAIN, CLUTCH, PRIMARY - S09PR6HSL/_S__SL/H_L (49SNOWDRIVECLUTCH09600TRG)   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- **Step-4**: no change.

### UPDATE-2 added Step-0:

**Step-0:** to pre-process the column `Assembly_name`, use *regexp_replace* + *split* to separate models# into a new column and remove it from the original column `Assembly_name`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, split

df0 = df.withColumn('new_col', split(regexp_replace('Assembly_name', r'^(.*)-\s*(\S+)(.*)$', '$1$3\0$2'),'\0')) \
    .selectExpr(
        'Itemno'
      , 'Assembly_id'
      , "coalesce(new_col[0], Assembly_name) as Assembly_name"
      , "coalesce(new_col[1], '') as models"
)

df0.show(truncate=False)
+-------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|Itemno |Assembly_id|Assembly_name                                                  |models              |
+-------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|0450056|44011      |OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY  (4999202399920239A06)                       |A01EA09CA           |
|0450056|135502     |OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY  (4999202399920239A06)                       |A02EA09CA/CB/CC     |
|0450056|37884      |OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY  (4999202399920239A06)                       |A01EA05CA           |
|0450067|12345      |DRIVE TRAIN, TRANSMISSION (6 SPEED)  ALL OPTIONS (49VICTRANS08)|V08AB26/GB26/LB26   |
|0450068|1000       |SUSPENSION (7043244)  (49SNOWSHOCKFRONT7043244SB)              |S09PR6HSL/PS6HSL/HEL|
|0450066|12345      |DRIVE TRAIN, CLUTCH, PRIMARY  (49SNOWDRIVECLUTCH09600TRG)      |S09PR6HSL/PS_HSL/H_L|
|0450069|12346      |DRIVE TRAIN, CLUTCH, PRIMARY (49SNOWDRIVECLUTCH09600TRG)       |                    |
+-------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

You can then process `Assembly_name` using RegexTokenier and StopwordsRemover, the `models` is a simplified version of the current post, which you can skip the Step-1, but do notice the depth of the arrays.

(Note: removed `S09PR6HSL/_S__SL/H_L` from the last record for testing)

Comment: May I ask last basic question? I know about ```\p{punct}``` class but I am not sure what all parts in ```(?:(?!/)\p{Punct}|\s)+'))``` means? I'm aware of using ```[\p{Punct}&&[^()]]``` in java which means all punctuations except ```(``` and ```)```. I have an idea but I am not sure of ```(?:(?!/)``` and ```\s)+'))``` in ```(?:(?!/)\p{Punct}|\s)+'))```. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Hi, @SachinSharma check https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html, the last column for \p{Punct}, you can find the corresponding ASCII which includes slash, so we prepend a negative lookahead `(?!/)` to exclude slash. `(?:A|B)` is to set up non-capturing group so we can implement `+` on one or more matches to this group. in this group, A is `(?!/)\p{Punct}` which matches any punctuation except slash and B is `\s` which is whitespace.

Comment: I've tested your solution which is awesome and posted my issues at the very bottom of the question so that you can update your solution or guide me on what else to embed in this solution to resolve these last issues of this weekend. Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Comment: Hi, @SachinSharma, check the updated post. the 1st one is an easy fix. the solution for the 2nd one could be slow. right now I don't have time to explain all the details for the new solution, so I just added them to the bottom. Just let me know if you have any questions. have a good weekend. :)

Comment: Hi @jxc, thanks a lot for your generous help. I've added last bullet point#3 at the end of the update section in question. Could you please let me know how to approach it. I've added a picture for a case but you can use existing strings e.g. ```DRIVE TRAIN, TRANSMISSION (6 SPEED) - V08AB26/GB26/LB26 ALL OPTIONS (49VICTRANS08)``` to explain it.

Comment: @SachinSharma, you want to remove `S09PR6HSL S09PS6HSL S09PR6HEL` or the like from the original column and then move them into a new column??

Comment: or you want to remove the chars between the hyphen and the opening parentheses (in the original text) for the new column?

Comment: Yes. ```These are model# which are embedded in the description field``` so I want to remove model# from original ```fit_assembly_name``` field and store description in one new column and model# in another new column and add these columns to the same dataframe. Mostly, model# are either substring joined together by ```/``` or they're as you mentioned in your comment, ```S09PR6HSL S09PS6HSL S09PR6HEL```.

Comment: For instance: Original String: ```SUSPENSION, REAR and SWING ARM - V07CB26/CD26 ALL OPTIONS (49VICSUSPRR07KING)```

After processing(removing punctuation, model#  (substrings either joined by ```/``` or start like S09 or A45(alphanumeric)), more than one white spaces between words and stop words): ```suspension rear and swing arm all options 49vicsusprr07king``` and store it in new column, added at the end of existing dataframe

Comment: @SachinSharma are these model# always shown in the field and preceded by a hyphen and followed by parentheses? I think this is just a pre-processing step to split the column into two.

Comment: as far as I can see in dataset, that's the case. they're always ```preceded by a hyphen and followed by parentheses but in some cases, there is no model# in the description field.``` I believe we can split existing column based on your logic and then clean new columns. I am still using ```step-1 to 4 solution``` and would fit your new solution in it as per your guidance.

Comment: @SachinSharma, updated, check the bottom of the post.

Comment: in case models# is missing, `Assembly_name` column will keep as is and `models` column will be EMPTY.

Comment: I'll test it real soon. I'll be brutally honest with the fact that I am clearly not good at utilizing regular expression logic in code ```r'^(.*)-([^(]+)(.*)$', '$1$3\0$2'``` logic part. Can you put some link here where I can learn this and practice a few problems on this. This always blocks me in spark work. Once again, ```thanks a lot!!!!!``` and I'll let you know if anything doesn't work.

Comment: n/p. I adjusted the regex pattern, since the ALL OPTIONS is before the opening parenthesis.

Comment: There is an issue. I'll attach the screenshot in question.

Comment: BTW. can you open a new question, there is not much room to add new content in the current post.

Comment: Sure. I added this issue here but for any further post. I'll open a new question and post the link here and will tag you.

Comment: @SachinSharma, this most like from a hython after the model#, can you adjust the pattern to:  `r'^(.*?)-\s*(\S+)(.*)$'`

Comment: it will fail if any texts before model# have a hyphen. if that's the case, will need to find more typical cases to decide the pattern.

Comment: just a follow-up, if you want to seriously learn regex and how it works, you will need to read this book:https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124

Comment: or check #regex tag in stackoverflow

Comment: ```Book ordered! Thanks for sharing it.``` I'm aspiring to be a good Data Engineer after graduation and at the moment, I am super new at it but I'm glad for your kind guidance. May I request you to connect with me via Gmail id and or Linkedin? 
At the moment, I am trying to join two data frames after processing and then write and save it as parquet file so that data scientist can use it from the location. I'll post question link here if I run into some issues. Again, Thanks a lot for . kind help!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201892/discussion-between-sachin-sharma-and-jxc).